# Do all Go projects need to live below GOPATH?

Tags: go, project

I am starting with Go and trying to get my head around `GOPATH` (and probably `GOBIN`).

When trying to fetch external libraries via `go get` I get the error

```
go get: no install location for directory D:\Seafile\dev-perso\domotiqueNG\services\dispatcher-go\src\dispatcher-go outside GOPATH
```

This error is apparently solved by having a project structure below `$GOPATH/src`.

Does this mean that all my Go programs must live there? If `GOPATH` is `d:\hello` then the projects `bonjour` and `aurvoir` really need to be in

```
d:\hello\src\bonjour
d:\hello\src\aurevoir
```

only ?

In this is the case how can I

- split, say, personal and professional projects when the personal must stay at `d:\home` and professional at `x:\work` ?
- have multilanguage projects where `d:\home\domotique\dispatch` is in Go, `d:\home\domotique\whatever` is in Python, and I have several such combos in `d:\home`?

Answer (score 8):

You can actually have Go projects outside of GOPATH. However, some tools do not work well or do not work at all in this kind of situation. For example, `goimports`, which formats your code and add missing imports, will not be able to find packages that are outside of GOPATH. You'll have to write the imports manually using a relative path: `./path/to/your/package`.

> how can I split, say, personal and professional projects when the personal must stay at d:\home and professional at x:\work ?

You actually can have multiple Go workspaces (https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH). You just need to set GOPATH to the list of their location joined with the list separator of your OS. e.g. on Linux it would look like this:

```
GOPATH="/home/nobody/perso:/home/nobody/work"
```

Though, I'm not sure how `go` and other tools such as dependency managers handle multiple workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

When using the GOPATH you can make subdirectories in the `/src` folder, for example, adding both home and work directories.  In fact, the Go project has an [example](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) of how to organize code.  While packages need to be in their own folders, a folder itself in the GOPATH is not automatically a package.

If you'd rather not work within the confines of the GOPATH, you can change it to the path you do want to work in, or set it to your home directory.